# Autoindent <head> and <body> in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

VSCode's formatter doesn't indent `<head>` and `<body>` tags by default. In the default settings the following lines exists:

```
// Indent <head> and <body> sections.
"html.format.indentInnerHtml": false,
```

I tried setting `html.format.indentInnerHtml` in the user settings to `true` but it didn't change anything.

This is what I get:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

This is what I want:

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you've saved changes to your settings.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the ["JS-CSS-HTML Formatter"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) extension installed, which was causing the problems. After uninstalling it, everything now works as expected.

Comment: I do not have the `lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter` extension installed and Visual Studio Code still doesn't indent `<head>` and `<body>`.

Answer (score 8):

**File/Preferences/Settings**

or shortcut

**Ctrl+Comma**

and change **html.format.indentInnerHtml** to `true`.

```
{
  "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true
}
```

more helpful settings on this website

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

Comment: This should have been marked as the correct answer. At least, this worked for me.